# Matplotlib cannot be used even installed - errors

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi everybody since im new to python 3 I tried to install Matplotlib in python but after installment there are multiple occuring errors

after importing matplotlip:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and run the program I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Panos/Desktop/Python/for_loop/for_loop.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: The specified module could not be found.
```

have anyone faced the same problem with matplotlib package using PyCharm as well?

other packages as Numpy or e.g. Pandas are working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I just tried a new install of an oldest version and it finally worked!
I didn't use pip install - I just went to PyCharms interpreter and selected matplotib package (using "+" button in the bottom left corner).

Then I checked to specify the version of the matlibplot package and after several efforts of installing-uninstalling matplotlib version the --> 3.1.3 worked for me without errors

```
from matplotlib import ft2font
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Hope that helps people with the same issue

- @Amin Kh thank you for your initial suggestion! :)))

Answer (score 0):

@Pan Pan try to install matplotlib 3.0.3 it fixed ft2font problem for some cases

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib==3.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you I tried that..unfortunatelly It produces an eroor while installing 3.0.3 edition - I tried previews editions as 3.3.2 of matplotlib but I get the same ft2font error :/